# Feeding a new item to index instantly in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

I have crawled and indexed some documents using SharePoint 2013 Search.I would like to feed index instantly when a new document is created.

How can i feed document index instantly using SharePoint 2013 Search?

Do you know feeding a new document to index instantly like docpush in SharePoint 2013 Search? (if it has a solution which is supported by Microsoft)

Thank you for your interests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible as there are no push api's in 2013.

Answer (score 1):

As Mikael said - there is no docpush.

But you can try to keep the index as fresh as possible with continous crawling, read http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219802.aspx